# Why can't I use the npx create-react-app command?

Tags: reactjs, npm, command, create-react-app, npx

My version of npm and npx is 6.14.4 and my operating system is Windows 10. Before I could use this command.

[Command line error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeI6z.jpg)

Comment: Clarify what command went wrong, what error you were shown.  check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could you share the complete log file that the error gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this feel free to help

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app "Name-Folder-App Must Be LowerCase"
```

Or if you work with yarn
`yarn create react-app my-app`

if you have any problem with your project of npm make that

```
npm i -f
```

Answer (score 0):

as stated by the create react app documentation:

> Creating an App
>
> You’ll need to have Node 8.16.0 or Node 10.16.0 or later version on
> your local development machine (but it’s not required on the server).
> You can use nvm (macOS/Linux) or nvm-windows to switch Node versions
> between different projects.

Here is the link for de [official documentation.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app)

So you need to update your current nodejs version.

Comment: I have upgraded my Node version to 8.16.0 but I still get the same error.